# How to select where in LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

```
public IList<ABVEvent> getListEvent(int ID)
{
    IList<ABVEvent> lstData = null;

    if (dbVietnalyze.DatabaseExists())
    {
        IQueryable<ABVEvent> strQuerry = from listEvent in db.listEvent select listEvent;
        lstData = strQuerry.ToList();
    }
    return lstData;
}
```

I want select `where`, for example in SQL: `select * from listEvent where id=ID`. I don't how to make select where in LinQ.

Comment: [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx).

Comment: why so many down votes?????

Comment: @Neel, lack of research effort, I would say.

Comment: I guess somebody should write the comment atleast tht why ur giving down votes coz people come on SO with expectation of learning something tht they donw know and if he or she gets so many downvotes without getting the reason I guess its not good for SO reputation @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @Neel, on the contrary. Stack Overflow aims for high-quality questions and answers, downvoting poor questions allows us to maintain a high signal to noise ratio. In the end, it is *good* for the site's "reputation".

Comment: it is rude @FrédéricHamidi how u can say this question poor?? I accept if somebody don't write code or he or she hasn't tried anything then its acceptable but here he has made some code and he are confused for "where" thing ..it would be a small or "poor" question for u coz ur very senior in this field but it might be something new for him...well I don't have any relation with this person who asked question but personally I didn't like so many downvotes and that too without any "reason" for that

Comment: @Neel, check out the link I provided in my first comment. That was the result of a simple Google search that took me something like five seconds. This question is poor because the questioner did not take these five seconds (or more) to search before asking, as explained in the site's help pages. Now, you only have my opinion, if you think I'm wrong and downvotes should not be piled like this (remember I only cast one), feel free to post your concerns on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: see @FrédéricHamidi please don't take it personally and I don't want to raise any complain neither I want to make this an issue I felt bad for so many downvotes that's it! and for what u said for "5 seconds" thing well there are many things in the world which would take hardly some seconds to understand but then also millions of questions are asked in different sites the difference is that some people are not that extra smart who can learn in 5 secs so that they come here and ask questions my only point is that instead of making so many downvot jst provide him decent answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
IQueryable<ABVEvent> strQuerry = from listEvent in db.listEvent 
                                 where listEvent.id = ID
                                 select listEvent;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = listEvent.Where(ob=>ob.id== ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq as

```
return lstData.Where( event => event.ID == ID ).ToList();
```

provided that ABVEvent has some member ID which is to be compared.